# Probability and dependent events

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

An unfair coin is flipped twice. $A$ is the event that heads comes up first followed by tails. $B$ is the event that tails comes up first followed by heads. The probability heads will come up is $p$. The likelihood that tails will come up is $1 - p$. What is $$P(A| A \cup B)$$

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hint

If $~p(A) = x~$ and $~p(B) = y$

then $p(A|A\cup B) = \frac{x}{x + y}.$

Comment: Worth noting that this only holds if A and B are mutually exclusive.